# Returning a value after a recursion in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

I decided to study some logic programming and I stumbled across a problem.
It is programmed in SWI Prolog.

```
test(A, B, N):-
 nonvar(B),
 B = final,
 true.

test(A, B, N):-
 N > 2,
 test(A, final, N).

test(A, B, N):-
 N1 is N + 1,
 test(N1, B, N1).
```

It is just a sample with no real use except it is driving me crazy.

The problem is that when the code reaches true then it starts tracking back and answers "true". But I need to "return" value A. How do I do that?

Comment: A quick question: what do you actually want the code to do?

Answer (score 8):

A is not being Unified with anything in the body of your rules. The way prolog works is via unification of terms. You cannot "return" A as in procedural languages as such. For instance, what do you want the value of A to be when the recursion comes to an end? I have no idea what your code is doing so let me use an example of my own.

```
  accumulate([], A, A).
  accumulate([H|T], A, N) :- A1 is A + H, accumulate(T, A1, N).

  sum([], 0).
  sum(L, N) :- accumulate(L,0,N).
```

Here is a sum procedure that will sum the values in a list and "return N", the sum of the values in the list. To call this procedure you can do this:

```
  sum([2, 3, 4], N).
```

And Prolog will respond:

```
  N = 9
```

Notice the accumulate procedure is using A as an accumulator as the recursion goes on. That is, A keeps the running sum, while N is the final answer it returns. During the recursion N is not unified with any real value.

In the final step of the recursion, that is, when the list is empty, the value of A is unified with N, in effect returning N.

---

Let us do a Trace.

```
 [trace] 4 ?- test(A, B, 0).
   Call: (7) test(_G417, _G418, 0) ? creep//A unifies with _G417 (internal variable name), B with _G418 and N with 0.
   Call: (8) nonvar(_G418) ? creep
   Fail: (8) nonvar(_G418) ? creep
   Redo: (7) test(_G417, _G418, 0) ? creep//Unifies with clause 2, 
^  Call: (8) 0>2 ? creep
^  Fail: (8) 0>2 ? creep
   Redo: (7) test(_G417, _G418, 0) ? creep //Unifies with clause 3
^  Call: (8) _L183 is 0+1 ? creep
^  Exit: (8) 1 is 0+1 ? creep
   Call: (8) test(1, _G418, 1) ? creep //recursive call, unifies with 
   Call: (9) nonvar(_G418) ? creep
   Fail: (9) nonvar(_G418) ? creep
   Redo: (8) test(1, _G418, 1) ? creep
^  Call: (9) 1>2 ? creep
^  Fail: (9) 1>2 ? creep
   Redo: (8) test(1, _G418, 1) ? creep
^  Call: (9) _L195 is 1+1 ? creep
^  Exit: (9) 2 is 1+1 ? creep
   Call: (9) test(2, _G418, 2) ? creep
   Call: (10) nonvar(_G418) ? creep
   Fail: (10) nonvar(_G418) ? creep
   Redo: (9) test(2, _G418, 2) ? creep
^  Call: (10) 2>2 ? creep
^  Fail: (10) 2>2 ? creep
   Redo: (9) test(2, _G418, 2) ? creep
^  Call: (10) _L207 is 2+1 ? creep
^  Exit: (10) 3 is 2+1 ? creep
   Call: (10) test(3, _G418, 3) ? creep
   Call: (11) nonvar(_G418) ? creep
   Fail: (11) nonvar(_G418) ? creep
   Redo: (10) test(3, _G418, 3) ? creep
^  Call: (11) 3>2 ? creep
^  Exit: (11) 3>2 ? creep
   Call: (11) test(3, final, 3) ? creep
   Call: (12) nonvar(final) ? creep
   Exit: (12) nonvar(final) ? creep
   Call: (12) final=final ? creep
   Exit: (12) final=final ? creep
   Call: (12) true ? creep
   Exit: (12) true ? creep
   Exit: (11) test(3, final, 3) ? creep
   Exit: (10) test(3, _G418, 3) ? creep
   Exit: (9) test(2, _G418, 2) ? creep
   Exit: (8) test(1, _G418, 1) ? creep
   Exit: (7) test(_G417, _G418, 0) ? creep
```

Now, notice the point in the trace where I marked `//A unifies with _G417 (internal variable name), B with _G418 and N with 0.`. At that point A is your external variable and _G417 is your internal A. If this call succeeds which it ultimately does prolog will only report the external variable values. Internally _G417 is never unified with anything else. I think the problem is one of understanding how the unification model of Prolog works.

Comment: I believe that my problem is a little bit different.

Look at my sample:
I ask Prolog test(A, B, 0).
Prolog goes though predicates and counts N1 until N1 is > 2. When this happen predicate calls recursively  test(A, final, N). So at this step A is 3, N is 3 and B is final. nonvar(B) succeeds, B = final succeeds so true is called. At this step Prolog stars backtracking and in the end returns true. But I asked about A and B, not true. I need the value A returned by Prolog.

Comment: I don't know how to force the predicate to terminate at the point where value A is assigned. I tried cuts but no success.

Comment: Vincent is right.  For a less noisy debug, try test(A, B, N):- write(triple(A,B,N)), N1 is N + 1, test(N1, B, N1). as the last clause.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have my prolog compiler here but have you tried something along the lines of:

```
test(A, B, N, A):-
 nonvar(B),
 B = final,
 true.

test(A, B, N, Result):-
 N > 2,
 test(A, final, N, Result).

test(A, B, N, Result):-
 N1 is N + 1,
 test(N1, B, N1, Result).
```

Comment: I need to return a value of variable A which is 3 when true is called. How do I achieve that? Your code above doesn't do that.

Thanks,
Petr

Comment: How about like this then? (I'll make this code work in 2h time when I'm back home)

Comment: The code above seems to run fine, I just tried it. Can you give me an example of a sample input/output?

Comment: It looks that your solution works. I have to go now so I'll test it tomorrow. But I'm confused. Why does Prolog returns true when there is only a single A and why does it return the value when there are two As in the first predicate?

Comment: It just seems to me that the variable Result is redundant.

Comment: It's not redundant. It basically only gets unified/assigned when you get to the end of the recursion so you can retrieve its value at the top level call.